# How to solve using definition of derivative for a constant function?

Tags: derivatives

$df\over dx$|$_{x=5}$ f(x)=2 is the problem I'm working with. I believe the definition of the derivative is $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\,$ but how would I find the answer using this definition? There's no x variable in the problem I was given, so I'm not sure what to plug in, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=2$ for all $x$ then $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{2-2}{h}=0$. Taking the limit again gives zero. Hence, $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)=0$ for all $x$, including $x=5$.

Answer (score 0):

You would be correct not to plug in anything, since there isn't an $x$ anywhere in the function.

So $f(x)=2$ and $f(x+h)=2$, and similarly, $f(5)=2$ and $f(5+h)=2$. Then using the definition,
$$f'(5)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to\infty}\dfrac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to\infty}\dfrac{2-2}{h}$$
$$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to\infty}0=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of $f$, $f(x+h)=2$ and $f(x)=2$. The rest is easy.